io.Copy on ssd costs too much time
Recently I developed a simple file upload server using the Go language. The key code is as follows:
func saveFile(r io.Reader, n int64) error {
    objectID := "1cb700e18a864328a561641736af934c"              // just an example
    objectPath := "/mnt/1c/b7/1cb700e18a864328a561641736af934c" // just an example
    var createDirStart, createFileStart, copyStart time.Time

    createDirStart = time.Now()
    if err := os.MkdirAll(filepath.Dir(objectPath), 0755); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    createFileStart = time.Now()
    f, err := os.Create(objectPath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer func() {
        syncStart := time.Now()
        if err == nil {
            err = f.Sync()
        }

        closeStart := time.Now()
        errc := f.Close()
        if err == nil {
            err = errc
        }
        if err != nil {
            os.Remove(objectPath)
        }
        fmt.Printf("objectId:%s, dirCost:%v, createFileCost:%v, copyCost:%v, syncCost:%v, totalCost:%v\n",
            objectID, createFileStart.Sub(createDirStart), copyStart.Sub(createFileStart), syncStart.Sub(copyStart),
            closeStart.Sub(syncStart), time.Since(createDirStart))
    }()

    copyStart = time.Now()
    if _, err = io.CopyN(f, r, n); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

for each uploaded file, a UUID is generated as its ID. To ensure that there are not too many files in a directory, I use the first two characters of the UUID as the first-level directory, and the next two characters as the second-level directory. The file name inside the second-level directory is the UUID itself, and the size generally does not exceed 500MB, usually 10MB. By printing the time spent at each step, I found that the IO.copy takes the most time, reaching up to several tens of seconds at most, but at this time, the system is not under much pressure. By tracking with blktrace, I found that the MAX indicator of the Q2G item is very large. I would appreciate it if any expert could help me take a look at what the problem is. Thank you very much.

my os version:
Linux version 5.4.0-153-generic (gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)) #170-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 16 13:43:31 UTC 2023
my go version:
go version go1.22.4 linux/amd64
my hardware ssd version:
Model Number: INTEL SSDPF2KX038TZ
Firmware Version: JCV10300
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID: 0x8086
IEEE OUI Identifier: 0x5cd2e4

io.Copy both reads and writes, have you ruled out any slowness on the reader side ?

From your log, it looks like you're writing many files at the same time. Are you sure that you're not just limited by the SSD write speed? Across all the concurrent writes, how many bytes/second are you writing?

And why are your log lines not in time order?!?

From the Red Hat Performance Tuning Guide:

If Q2G is very high, it means that there are a lot of requests queued concurrently. This could indicate that the storage is unable to keep up with the I/O load.

So, you should benchmark this with different machines - it is very unlikely that Go is the culprit for a high Queue-to-GetRequest time. Maybe the guys on Super User know more, I think the comment from DrMoishe Pippik might hit a nerve:

large writes exceeding cache size may be f a r slower.

